# Qt3D, get object picked with QPickEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I have lots of entities that has a QObjectPicker attached. I Connect all those QObjectPicker to a function `clicked(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent* event)`. Is there a way to get from `event` the QEntity (for example) of the object which was picked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the `clicked()` callback to the QEntity:

```
connect(m_objectPicker, &QObjectPicker::clicked, 
        yourEntityInstance, &yourEntity::handlePickerClicked);
```

You then know which entity was clicked as the QEntity is receiving the callback.

Comment: That only works if the object picker is attached to a leaf entity of the scene graph. If it’s further up the graph it may fire for any of the child entities that have geometry

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a design decision by Qt, to drive developers to a better solution.

The trick is to create your own subclass from QEntity that holds your entity and the mesh and any other information. This class can then handle distinguishing between different click events.

```
class ViewObject : public Qt3DCore::QEntity
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ViewObject(Qt3DCore::QEntity* parent, Qt3DCore::QComponent* mesh);

private slots:
    void onClicked(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent* event);

private:
    Qt3DCore::QComponent* m_mesh{};
};
```

...

```
auto objectPicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(this);
objectPicker->setHoverEnabled(false);
objectPicker->setEnabled(true);
QObject::connect(objectPicker, SIGNAL(clicked(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent*)), this, SLOT(onClicked(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent*)));
addComponent(objectPicker);
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is missing unfortunately. If you're willing to use private API, the [QPickEventPrivate](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/render/picking/qpickevent_p.h?h=dev) contains the nodeId of the picked entity.

Comment: I would refrain from using the private API as it might change in future versions. It's probably best to stick to the other answers.

Comment: A public property was added to the event in 5.13 or upcoming 5.14

Answer (score 0):

I'll add how I achieved this to the already good answers because what I did is fairly easy to port to other parts of you program where you might need similar functionality - without having to implement any subclasses.

What you can do in Qt is use lambdas to connect signals and slots like so:

```cpp
connect(m_objectPicker, &QObjectPicker::clicked, [this, i]() {pickerClicked(i);});
```

If you store the `QEntity` corresponding to index `i` you can retrieve in the method `pickerClicked(int i)` that you need to implement on `this` (I assume your controller class or the like).

I generated the object pickers procedurally that's why I used indices but you could use e.g. strings as well.